# Android - Frame by frame animation, over 100 frames workaround?

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to perform the operation stated in the title. 
Code works absolutely fine for 20 frames.
However when I run the program for 50 frames, the buttons within the activity stops responding.
When I run the program for 100 frames there is only a black screen followed by the error "this program terminated abnormally".

The method I use is to define an animation list on an xml file and set it as background.

I think I have to use a more advanced approach. Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: you should provide some code..

Comment: there really isn't much to tell, there is nothing wrong with the code as it works perfectly fine for 20 or less frames, all frames constructed using the same tool. Just looking for a better way to create frame by frame animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the wrong usage of constraints and folders.

The images where staying at the location /drawable-ldpi

When I relocated the images to the location /drawable-hdpi

The problem was solved.